# Why would dropbox cause an increase in Latency

Tags: performance, internet, dropbox, latency

I am trying to figure out why Dropbox seems to be completely disturbing my internet connection and if others may be having the same problem.

When Dropbox is idle, I ran a speed test. I get a ping to the server of about 30ms, a download speed of 21.5 Mbps, and an upstream of 1.5 Mbps.

As soon as I add a new file to my folder the connection (for any computer on my LAN) is degraded.

I ran the same speed test while uploading to Dropbox. The server ping increases to 539ms, downstream speed drops to 1.77 Mbps, and the upstream drops to .1 Mbps.

I have AT&T UVerse service on their 18 Mbps data plan. I also have tried limiting Dropbox's bandwidth for uploads to under 200Kbps. It seems that regardless of the settings, I see the same service degradation.

I'm at a loss for what to check next... or what could be causing the problem.

Comment: [Here](http://forums.comcast.com/t5/Basic-Internet-Connectivity-And/Dropbox-Uploads-Destroy-Latency-and-Download-Performance/td-p/1880711) is someone with a similar problem. (no solution yet) You could try to limit the up- and download of dropbox to see if it helps. You can do this in the dropbox preferences itself.

Comment: I have adjusted those settings... down to as low as 100k up and 1 mbps down with no luck... as soon as anything starts to upload to dropbox i see the degradation in performance

Comment: Those are kilobytes (not kilobits) so try an even lower number like 10kB up and 10kB down (really wringing dropboxs neck:) to see if it helps. Just for troubleshooting. And did you test the download/ping during a download of a 100 or 1000mb testfile (you can search google for such files).

Comment: downloading a 1000mb test file the ping is normal downstream is reduced but thats expected...  I tried reducing to a rediculously slow upload in the dropbox properties as soon as it starts syncing my ping downstream and upstream all go south...

Comment: [Another one](http://www.alexstanhope.com/blog/technology/140/windows-7-high-ping-times) with the same problem but solved it. Do you have the virusscanner/security disabled? And could you test uploading a video to youtube and seeing if it also disrupts normal internet speeds.